# Query a csv file and get the record nearest to my latitude & longitude

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, geolocation

the main goal of this node project is to get the city that i am in, or the nearest one if thats not available.

To start, I have made a notepad csv file which contains the fields: city, country, lat and long. Here it is below. Its filled with lots and lots of cities.

[image]

Is there any npm module that I could use to query this file. I dont want to use an external database.

I know actual databases sometimes have geo features to allow queries to work out the distance between 2 sets of lat and long coordinates. How would I go about doing that?

Thanks for any info

Answer (score 0):

[Gdal](https://naturalatlas.github.io/node-gdal/classes/gdal.Geometry.html#method-distance) has a feature to calculate distance between two points. What I can think is building a point layer on the fly with gdal and calculate distance between those cities and your city and find the nearest one.